# Source "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File import callback not supported FOUNDRY ERROR

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, foundry-code-repositories

I'm doing udemy course about solidity, and I have encounter this error in Foundry contract:

Source "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

I have managed to solve this for HARDHAT and TRUFFLE by deleting "node_modules" from Juan's Blanco solidity addon in VSC but I can't do it for Foundry.

I have also tried to change workspace compilet to LocalFile, or NodeModule as per other posts in here but nothing worked.

Just to be clear, everything compiled correctly but still get this error which is kinda annoying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using an external dependency you need to

- [Install the dependency](https://book.getfoundry.sh/projects/dependencies)
- [Configure it to match your Solidity source code using remappings.txt if needed](https://book.getfoundry.sh/projects/dependencies)

As your question lacks details, it is not possible to tell which of these steps you have done and which solutions you have attempted so far.

Comment: Remapping solved my issue :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple. I had the same issue and couldn't find a way around it. You have to re-install Solidity extension from Juan Blanco and install v. 0.0.135. Then reload.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add openzeppelin-contracts as a git submodule first

```
[submodule "lib/openzeppelin-contracts"]
    path = lib/openzeppelin-contracts
    url = https://github.com/openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
```

then, you need to do remapping(in remappings.txt)

```
openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
```